# How much running is advisable for over weight person?

Tags: running, weight-loss, bodyweight

I am 5 feet 11 inches tall and weigh about 95 kilograms. Is it advisable to jog/run for 20 minutes a day? Do i risk injuring my knees?
The idea behind runnning is to loose weight and gain a lot of endurance and stamina. 
I have been doing squats and lunges to strengthen my leg muscles.

EDIT:
I would like to ask the similar question about skipping/jump ropes. Would jumping for about 2 minutes every day (about 100 jumps) cause serious longterm injuries? I find jumping ropes very enjoyable exercise, but I sometimes get dull ache (stiffness) just above the knees and hence the question

Comment: How far have you been walking?

Comment: Also, do you do weighted squats or just free squats? And how many?

Comment: We need your fitness background information to access your capabilities,  have you taken part in competitive sports before?

Comment: I do about 20x3 sets of free squats. I have been jogging for about 2 km at a stretch. I have never taken part in competitive sports.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Before you run ensure you got to a trusted running shop to get the right shoes. Then walk and jog, maybe 5 minutes on day one. Then slowly build up. It may take you longer to get to your distance/time but it is quicker than getting an injury.

Ensure you warm up and warm down correctly, practice makes perfect but do not over do it. If you pull a muscle, stop, rest and recover. Look for something like Park Run and a local running group/club there is often clubs or groups for beginners to get help with starting out. Nothing beats someone going out with you to help.

Lastly try to swim to, it will burn more fat and helps your body recover from the run.

Comment: And you were doing so well until the last sentence. Do you have any backup for your claim that swimming burns more fat than running?

Comment: So if I understand correctly, if I go slow with right surface and right shoes I should be able to build strength and stamina. Thanks for your inputs Indofraiser

Comment: Long term it will, minute again minute it will not. However we are looking at a longer term solution by the sounds of it, also helps with recovery, toning and less likely to get injured so ideal short, medium and long term compliment to running.

Answer (score 0):

Shoes are a good place to start but the key is to find a goal and then look at a plan to meet that goal. A reasonably good goal for a beginner is to finish a 5k. There are myriad good plans for "couch to 5k" and they are all just a google search away. I would recommend looking at something like active.com or something similar. The key when you start is to remember that the hardest part of running can often be the first two minutes aka. getting out of the door and getting going. You should be running at a pace where you can hold a conversation but not too easily.